# Non-infrastructure distributed vector processing in R

Tags: r, spatial-analysis

Is there a non infrastructure R option similar to disk.frame for geospatial vector distributed processing? I have come across the geospark package but am not sure if it requires spark to be installed.

Disk.frame is a local non-infrastructure install that allows for distributed processing similar to that of Dask, Spark, etc. Below is the description:

https://diskframe.com/

> How do I manipulate tabular data that doesn’t fit into Random Access
> Memory (RAM)?
>
> Use {disk.frame}!
>
> In a nutshell, {disk.frame} makes use of two simple ideas
>
> 1. split up a larger-than-RAM dataset into chunks and store each chunk
>    in a separate file inside a folder
> 2. provide a convenient API to
>    manipulate these chunks
>
> {disk.frame} performs a similar role to distributed systems such as
> Apache Spark, Python’s Dask, and Julia’s JuliaDB.jl for medium data
> which are datasets that are too large for RAM but not quite large
> enough to qualify as big data.

As far as use cases I am thinking of point-to-point, point-in-polygon, etc. type of analysis, specifically for R.

Comment: Not sure what "non-infrastructure" means here. I don't understand how "non-infrastructure" can also be "distributed". Distributed across what, if not an infrastructure of some sort?

Comment: Well non-intrastructure would be mean that you dont need to install something like a database or other software (i.e. Postgres, Spark, etc.). If you look at disk.frame it is a package that splits a dataframe into "chunks" as files, then those files can be processes on a core of the CPU, hence the distributed. But within the disk.frame package it allows for use of dplyr syntax and bringing the results back as a single dataframe. Having this as an option allows for fast data exploration without the need for IT management and priviledges

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of a roll-your-own solution: have your bigger-than-RAM spatial data in a GeoPackage with an indexed row number column, select chunks using `st_read` with some SQL in the `query` parameter to select only a bunch of rows, then iterate using R's standard parallel-over-multiple-cores tools (e.g. `library(foreach)`) and manually reassembling the results (`foreach` might do a lot of this for you).

Exact details will depend on what you are doing. If you have a bigger-than-RAM set of points (which is a heck of a lot of points) and a smaller-than-RAM set of polygons and want to do point-in-polygons then load all the polygons and do a split-test-combine with the points. If you have points and polygons that are bigger than RAM then you'll need to split *both* and do a nested loop, with the inner loop testing if a point is in a subset of your polygons.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was thinking too, but I wasn't sure if I was missing something, much appreciated

Comment: `sf` data frames use list-columns for the geometry and these aren't supported in `disk.frame`. Might be worth asking the devs of that package if they are interested in a `spatial.disk.frame`?

Comment: My thoughts exactly